# Queued messages do not get sent when shutting down a publisher

Tags: ros, queue, publisher, messages, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that when calling `publisher.shutdown()`, the messages that are queued for publishing simply get destroyed with the publisher. I could not find any documentation that specified this behavior.

It seems unintuitive to me, especially if I compare to other systems. For example, when I write an e-mail, click send, and close the mail application, it will not just delete the e-mail if it is not yet sent.

I know that when ROS started, it was designed to send streams of data where the loss of a few messages was not important, but this is not always the case. In the applications developed in my project for example, every message is important, and many of them are sent only once. I would therefore need a way to shut down a publisher without losing any messages.

Here's an example that shows the problem:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "MyPublisher");

    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");

    ros::Rate oneSecond(1);

    int num = 1;
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String > ("/MyTopic", 10);

        // Waits for the subscribers to connect
        oneSecond.sleep();

        std_msgs::String msg;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Hello World! " << num++;
        msg.data = ss.str();
        pub.publish(msg);
        
        pub.shutdown();
        
        // Moving this line above the shutdown solves the problem
        oneSecond.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In that example, the subscribers never get any message, because the publisher gets shut down before its messages get sent. Swapping `shutdown()` and `sleep()` solves the problem.

I am wondering how to solve this properly. Waiting a second before every `shutdown()` in my application is not nice, and is problematic when it is in the GUI thread (the whole GUI would freeze). Also, I am not guaranteed that one second is enough.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50341/queued-messages-do-not-get-sent-when-shutting-down-a-publisher/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-13**:
You are correct. Messages do get lost. Most nodes that care about it do something similar to your sleep before shutdown. It would be nice to have a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Solution #1

One possible solution would be to modify `shutdown` as such:

`Publisher::shutdown(bool sendQueuedMessages = false)`.

Calling `shutdown` with `true` would "kill" the instance as usual, but the `TopicManager` would not call `Publication::drop()` but rather mark the `Publication` as `isShuttingDown=true`.

At the next call to `processPublishQueues()`, after sending all messages, the `TopicManager` would call `drop()` on all `Publication` instances marked to be shut down.

In the case where a new publisher for the same topic gets created in the mean time (after `shutdown` but before `processPublishQueues`), the `TopicManager` would simply unmark the `Publication` as shutting down.

### Solution #2

Another possibility would be to create a method `Publisher::areQueuesEmpty()`. The `Publisher` would ask the `TopicManager`, which would ask the `Publication`, which would ask all `SubscriberLink`s. Only if all queues for all subscribers are empty would the method return true. The developers would then have to manually manage when they shut down the publisher.

---

Originally posted by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) with karma: 867 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25986/dinesh/) on 2016-07-19**:
Note that these are not solutions, but rather proposals, none of which are available in ROS Kinetic. I couldn't find any workaround that currently works.